# PHP code to compare dates and display current date

Tags: php, mysql, html

Ok guysI'm going to cut to the chase; I'm new to php so I have been messing around with trying to display a date on a calendar; thing is its easy just to pull from a database and display what I'm trying to create is this

if the date has passed then let it say " date has passed" but if not i want it to display the code heres what i got so far.

```
<?php // get the day of today
$today = date('z');

// you can pass any date to the strtotime function
$day = date('z', strtotime($row_SpartanRecordNew['date']));

// check to see if the date has passed
echo ($day < $today)?"Date has passed":"date in the future";



 ?>



 <td align="center"><?php echo ($day < $today)?"Date has passed": echo $row_RecordNew['date'] ?> </td>
```

that last echo part doesn't push through the value, am i doing anything wrong? who can guide me

Comment: date('z') only gives you a day of the year, not a true date. You would be better using date() to compare unix timestamps.

Comment: This is easier and more agile with `\DateTime();` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the ternary operator incorrectly:

```
echo ($day < $today)?"Date has passed": $row_RecordNew['date'];
```

The part inside the brackets is a boolean, then the first option is for true, the second is for false - but in this case, it is always going to echo something.

Think of it this way:

```
function (true/false condition)? do this if true: do this if false;
```

Secondly, `date()` is a function normally used to output a formatted date string. If you are comparing unix timestamps (the output of a strtotime) you probably want to simply set `$day` to also be a unix timestamp using `time()` instead of `date()` like this:

```
$today = time();
$day = strtotime($row_SpartanRecordNew['date']);

// check to see if the date has passed
echo ($day < $today)?"Date has passed":"date in the future";
```